# MySQL типы varchar и text

Tags: mysql, innodb, percona

хотелось бы у экспертного сообщества выяснить некоторые аспекты использования типов данных varchar/text в MySQL. Я даже не знаю, может ли данный вопрос получить какой-то объективный принятый ответ, но может быть можно собрать какой-то комьюнити-ответ, или несколько ответ по различным аспектам.
Итак, есть у в базах столбцы, которые сейчас имеют тип `varchar(N)`, и иногда приходится эту длину расширять. Появилась мысль просто сделать его `text`. В связи с этим всплыли вопросы, касающиеся различного рода сайд-эффектов таких преобразований, начиная от места и объема хранения, заканчивая влиянием на место сортировки результатов выборки.
Я, конечно, пробежался по докам, хотелось бы более содержательного и практического ответа, с отсылками к литературе или документации.

Можно также рассматривать ситуации с позиции объемов таблиц, маленькие нас особо, конечно, не волнуют, но когда речь идет о десятках и сотнях гигабайт, возможно есть свои нюансы.

> Скажу честно, до вчерашнего дня, я, наверное, даже и не знал, что у таблиц может быть разный `row_format`. В общем мы используем `dynamic`, видимо, это вариант "по умолчанию".  Чуть отклоняясь от темы, проверил, что перевод тестовой таблицы (`int,text`) объемом 500Мбайт, в формат `compressed` сжал ее до 230мбайт.

Насколько я понимаю из [документации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-row-format.html) в dynamic-формате, строки переменной длины СУБД может хранить как и в самой таблице, так и вне ее:

> When a table is created with ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC, InnoDB can store long variable-length column values (for VARCHAR, VARBINARY, and BLOB and TEXT types) fully off-page, with the clustered index record containing only a 20-byte pointer to the overflow page... Whether columns are stored off-page depends on the page size and the total size of the row. When a row is too long, the longest columns are chosen for off-page storage until the clustered index record fits on the B-tree page. TEXT and BLOB columns that are less than or equal to 40 bytes are stored in line. The DYNAMIC row format maintains the efficiency of storing the entire row in the index node if it fits (as do the COMPACT and REDUNDANT formats), but the DYNAMIC row format avoids the problem of filling B-tree nodes with a large number of data bytes of long columns. The DYNAMIC row format is based on the idea that if a portion of a long data value is stored off-page, it is usually most efficient to store the entire value off-page. With DYNAMIC format, shorter columns are likely to remain in the B-tree node, minimizing the number of overflow pages required for a given row.

Я так понимаю, что если содержимое влезает в длину строки таблицы, то оно здесь же и хранится. Если не влезает, то самые длинные столбцы переносятся во внешнее хранение (off-page). Тут мне несколько не ясно, это верно для обоих типов, как `varchar` так и `text`? Text при этом видимо автоматически назначаются "самыми длинными" и переносятся во вне?

Следует ли на практике вообще избегать по возможности этого off-page хранения, может ли оно быть заметно при использовании и в каких сценариях?
Также следует ли тут считать хранение "в таблице" наиболее эффективным. И, если, например, у меня есть пара столбцов условных `varchar(5000)` то проще их таковыми и оставить (или расширить например, до 10к) но не преобразовывать в `text`. Если я делаю 2 столбца `text`, но контент конкретной строки влазит в строку таблицы, то разницы между varchar/text нет?

Еще интересует вопрос, есть ли разница в объеме занимаемом таблицей на диске при определении столбцов разных форматах. Этого я доках что-то даже не встретил.

Тема создания индексов на данных столбцах (и сортировки по ним) меня мало интересует, ибо рассматривается вопрос о просто хранении полей, а не поиска. (хотя если кто-то затронет это в ответе, то явно хуже не будет, ибо свои ограничения там тоже есть).

И последний, основной вопрос, с которого я углубился в изучение, следующий ([линк](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html)):

> Instances of BLOB or TEXT columns in the result of a query that is processed using a temporary table causes the server to use a table on disk rather than in memory because the MEMORY storage engine does not support those data types . Use of disk incurs a performance penalty, so include BLOB or TEXT columns in the query result only if they are really needed.

В общем говоря, если результат запроса содержит `text` поля, то таковые запросы сортируются во [временной таблице](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-temporary-tables.html) на диске, а не в памяти?
зы: из-за этого будем видеть `using temporary, using filesort` в плане выполнения?

В общем подытожить если:

- Скорость работы в условиях внешнего хранения, и критерии когда оно становится внешним
- размер занимаемый таблицей на диске, при различных вариантах форматов
- Влияния на скорость сортировок и выборок, при работе с полями, и возможно другие аспекты, которые не мне попались под руку.

*зы: наверное, по данному вопросу главу книги можно написать, если таковые есть на примете, то ссылки приветствуются.*

Comment: *столбцы, которые сейчас имеют тип varchar(N), и иногда приходится эту длину расширять* Вот тут не вижу проблемы. Чистая IN_PLACE операция, простая как две копейки и быстрая. *Появилась мысль просто сделать его text.* А тут нужно исходить из соображения "А доколе оно может расшириться". Если там пахнет переходом за 50 кбайт - то да, иначе нафига бы? *заканчивая влиянием на место сортировки результатов выборки.* Сортировка по столь длинным строкам? вот не встречал на практике... да и фантазия пасует. Нафига?

Comment: *Я так понимаю, что если содержимое влезает в длину строки таблицы, то оно здесь же и хранится.* Может храниться. Но не обязано. А уж что в каждом конкретном случае взбредёт в голову этим пчёлам - не угадаешь... *это верно для обоих типов, как varchar так и text?* Да. *Text при этом видимо автоматически назначаются "самыми длинными" и переносятся во вне?* Нет. Сервер оперирует реальными данными, а не абстрактными соображениями. *следует ли тут считать хранение "в таблице" наиболее эффективным.* Скорее наоборот. Tablescan - обычное дело, а тут строка в теле выйдет боком.

Comment: *есть ли разница в объеме занимаемом таблицей на диске при определении столбцов разных форматах.* После optimize table размер отличается незначительно. А вот внешнее хранилище, в отличие от тела таблицы, очень даже повторно использует свободные блоки. *если результат запроса содержит text поля, то таковые запросы сортируются во временной таблице на диске, а не в памяти?* Ты неправильно понял, что написано. Тут не о сортировке, а о хранении данных. Если в структуре есть text/blob, то memory-таблица (или кэш запроса) волшебным образом превращается в myisam и хранится не в памяти, а на диске.

Comment: @Akina спс. последнее твое из первого коммента, это как раз к последнему третьего коммента относится - Про сортировку тут и правда хз откуда у меня появилось. А так да, сказано ["Some query conditions prevent the use of an in-memory temporary table, in which case the server uses an on-disk table instead:   Presence of a BLOB or TEXT column in the table. "](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-temporary-tables.html). То есть да, не про сортировку, а просто, что если для запроса используется временная таблица, то с участием текст это точно будет таблица на диске, а не в памяти.